python selenium: подгрузка куки-файлов
Я знаю про библиотеку pickle, но она использует свой формат хранения куки-файлов. Мне же нужно загрузить куки-файлы из google chrome. Я скопировал файл Cookies и кинул в ту же директорию, где и сам код. Подскажите, как можно подгружать эти куки?
